# Spark Excel : class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream is not implementing InputStreamStatistics

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run the spark application which reads excel file to dataframe using spark crealytics package.
However I am getting the below error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream of class class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream is not implementing InputStreamStatistics.
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.<init>(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipStream(ZipHelper.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:104)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:298)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:314)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:296)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:214)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:180)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$openWorkbook$2$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:66)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$openWorkbook$2$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:66)
    at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:158)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$openWorkbook$2.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:66)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$openWorkbook$2.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:66)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.openWorkbook(ExcelRelation.scala:64)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.excerpt$lzycompute(ExcelRelation.scala:71)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.excerpt(ExcelRelation.scala:70)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$inferSchema$1.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:264)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation$$anonfun$inferSchema$1.apply(ExcelRelation.scala:263)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.inferSchema(ExcelRelation.scala:263)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.<init>(ExcelRelation.scala:91)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:39)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:14)
    at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:8)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
```

I have added the below maven dependancy too.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
```

Still same issue. Please help.

Following is the code snippet

```
 val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").
  option("useHeader", "true").
  option("sheetName", "Sheet1").
  option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true").
  option("inferSchema", "false").
  option("addColorColumns", "False").
  load("/user/my_id/101.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after upgrading to Spark 3.0.2